# Links inside a turbo frame with data-turbo-action="replace" (for instance: pagination links) are triggering 'turbo:load' on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo, turbo-rails

Picture a very common use-case described in the [official Handbook](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/frames#promoting-a-frame-navigation-to-a-page-visit): a `<turbo-frame>` that contains pagination links.

So, turbo supports (encourages?) annotating these pagination links with `data-turbo-action="replace"`, and the resulting experience is very nice: browser URL gets updated, a page reload will load the correct pagination and the browser back button will show the last page loaded correcly.

However, as soon as you add `data-turbo-action="replace"` on any link, they start firing a `turbo:load` event on the page when clicked, even tough they are **inside** a `<turbo-frame>`; in my mind, `turbo:load` should be analogous to a `DOMContentLoaded` event, and it should fire only ONCE per page loaded; if a turbo frame is being navigated by pagination, I don't want my event handlers designed for the page that contains the `turbo-frame` to be fired again and again each time a frame within the page paginates.

Note that this ONLY happens if `data-turbo-action` is present; otherwise, the links inside the turbo-frame will not trigger a `turbo:load` on the page.

Lastly, the `turbo:load` event being fired is indistinguishable from the one on the first page load or from a full turbo visit outside the turbo-frame; it's `target` is the page's root `html` element, so I can't even detect it was a `turbo:load` coming from a turbo-frame.

So, how to avoid links clicked inside a `<turbo-frame>` that were marked with `data-turbo-action="replace"` to trigger `turbo:load` on the page, or at least distinguish these events from the sole `turbo:load` fired as soon as the page loads for the first time?